# Grails - How can I calculate execution time spent on any action?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to measure time spent on every action of my application, since I'm rebuilding a legacy system.

Right now I'm doing this at Controller level:

```
def actionStart() {
    session.startTime = new Date().getTime()
}
def actionEnd() {
    def endTime = new Date().getTime()
    timeHandler(endTime, session.startTime)
}
def timeHandler(end, start){
    return end - start
}
```

Important: I want to move it to a Filter and automatically execute it at the start and ending of every action.

What should be the best approach? Thanks in advance.

PS.: What's the difference between getting `System.currentTimeMillis()` and instanciating an object? Performance?

Answer (score 5):

At the start of the action do Like this :

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

at the end of the Action , do Like  this :

```
System.out.println( (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + " ms");
```

and put your action between this two line

**Disclaimer:**

I answered this question according to java (before the tags was edited), so please clarify your tags.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [Grails filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html) to do this:

```
class TimeFilters {
    def filters = {
        timeCheck(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = { model ->
                ...
            }
            after = { model ->
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the source code of `java.util.Date`:

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

So this is just a performance overhead to create and get time: `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: How does this help to calculate the time?  Would you just print out the current time in both closures then do some correlation & math afterward?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with using methods afterInceptor and beforeInceptor

```
def actionArray = [:];

def afterInterceptor = {
        def time = System.currentTimeMillis() - actionArray[actionUri]
        println("Used time for action " + actionUri + "is: " + time + " ms");
    }

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        actionArray[actionUri] = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This came up today, mentioned on DZone / GroovyMag: [GProf is a profiler for Groovy](http://nagaimasato.blogspot.com/2013/04/gprof-was-just-born.html)